# Display a route from Google maps place ID with javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a link to a Map/Place. The urls look like `https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=18y_Gahydj0rBHluofKO0wxHLBLI&ll=51.16842583802143%2C-0.8371334530562535&z=17` so I'm guessing the place ID is `Gahydj0rBHluofKO0wxHLBLI`

View the link [here](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=18y_Gahydj0rBHluofKO0wxHLBLI&ll=51.16842583802143%2C-0.8371334530562535&z=17)

That link has a route on it. I'm trying to display that route on a map using the javascript maps api but I'm struggling to get it working.

Not sure how the route is stored and how I should be accessing it?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?forcekml%3D1%26mid%3D18y_Gahydj0rBHluofKO0wxHLBLI)?

Comment: Ah yes, just like that! Hows that done then? Do I include that url as the source for the KML layer?

Comment: Yes, and doesn't need to be URL encoded